# Find SQL datetimes contained a given list

Tags: sql, list, datetime, filtering

I'd like to do something like this:

```
SELECT TABLE.DATE FROM TABLE
WHERE TABLE.DATE IN ("2015-07-23 09:02:11", "2016-06-15 17:23:55", "2017-08-01 23:15:43", "2019-03-12 11:12:32", ...);
```

> Unknown column '2015-07-23 09:02:11' in 'where clause'

What would be the correct syntax to do this? I already know the exact datetimes and have them as strings in a list?

I should also mention, that I am using a commercial database (SAP derivate).

Comment: The syntax is fine, at least what you have shown so far.  Have you tried an actual query yet?

Comment: Alternatively, you could also store the dates in a separate table, and do a JOIN.

Comment: My bad, I edited the question (see above).

Comment: Once again edited. They look like this: "DATETIME_STR_1", "DATETIME_STR_2", "DATETIME_STR_3", ...

Comment: Show an example of the value from `TABLE.DATE` and a value provided instead of `DATETIME_STR_1`. PS. In MySQL you must use single quote `'` for string literals, not double quote `"` which are used as JSON paths/values delimiter.

Comment: So you have a list of datetimes but in table you only have dates?

Comment: I added the values. I have them as strings. @Salman A: In the TABLE.DATE I have the data type TIMESTAMP.

Comment: You might be getting an error saying `Unknown column '2015-07-23 09:02:11' in 'where clause'` :(

Comment: Yes, this was the error due to the wrong quotation marks. I could fix this.